# redirecting between 4 pages html5

Tags: jquery, html, redirect, browser-history

All

I am creating a website that has 4 pages.

1)home page

2)signup page

3)login page

4)password reset page

the scenario is:

user is in home page,on clicking a button the user goes to signup page,
after successful signup,user is redirected to login page.
after user first login, he is redirected to password reset page,
when user click on continue button. after changing password, the user is automatically redirected to signup page

I think the client is using some session that takes history url.

can any body help me out of this.

I tried the following so that url will not be stored in history

1)history.js; History.replaceState('state','title', url);

2)windows.location.replace('url');

Comment: AFAIK there is no way for a javascript redirect not to store history. Your best bet is for the `Change Password` page to invalidate the session hash and to redirect based on that.

Comment: What is the problem? You do not want which url to be stored in the history?

Comment: I dont want the signup page to be stored in history..

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the scenario:

**1. Home Page to Sign Up page**

This can be achieved by putting a href link on the SIGN UP / or any other keyword  which will make the user goes directly to the signup page on click.

**2. Sign Up to Login Page**

When the user fills out the form correctly (can be validated by JQuery or server-side language), the data is stored in DB for example and you can put a column (*reset*) in the user table for example and set the value to 1 and the user can be redirected to the Log In page via Jquery (windows.href) or by the server-side language you are using after the process is over.

**3. Log in to reset Page**

When the user now log in with its credential, you check for the username and password is correct or not. If correct, then check if the *reset column* for this user is equal to 1 or 0. If 1, means the user should reset it's password. Thus, you redirect the user to the reset page.

**4. Reset to Sign Up**

If the reset process is done correctly, you just bring the user to the Sign Up page after the process.